# Loading a json File with UTF-8 Encoded Strings?

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to load a json file (JSON Array) to javascript by using this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.json", //contains array of json objects
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json[0].name);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

The value of `json[0].name` is:

```
//in data.json, it is like this (it is Arabic):
\u00cd\u00ed\/\u00c3\u00d4\u00c8\u00ed\u00e1\u00ed\u00e5 \u00c7\u00e1\u00e3\u00e4\u00d8\u00de\u00c9 \u00c7\u00e1\u00ce\u00c7\u00e3\u00d3\u00c9 \u00da\u00d4\u00d1

//console.log(json[0].name) gives this instead
Íí/ÃÔÈíáíå ÇáãäØÞÉ ÇáÑÇÈÚÉ ÚÔÑ
```

The `data.json` file was automatically generated by a PHP script, where I used `utf8_encode()` to encode Arabic strings and correctly store them in the file.

I think it is an encoding issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you mean `utf8_encode`? I don't think that function does what you think it does. It only supports conversion from ISO-8859-1 (i.e. latin-1 encoding), which does not support Arabic. The JavaScript seems to be working correctly, it's your server side code that's wrong so you might want to post that instead.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes, `utf8_encode()`. I used it because (in the server side) I was reading from csv file and doing some computation before saving the json file. I think that's why it was the only way I could get a _valid_ json that contains Arabic.

Comment: Well you shouldn't be using `utf8_encode` for Arabic text ever because ISO-8859-1 does not support Arabic. If you need conversion from another encoding (I don't know what encoding your original file is in), look into `iconv` and such.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Ok, but isn't the `\u00cd\u00ed....` string a valud Unicode string? Why `console.log()` produces a different string?

Comment: It's a valid string of Unicode escapes (which are not needed if your system is working, you can just output UTF-8 text as-is), yes, but it represents meaningless characters. The JavaScript code is outputting exactly what your server gave it - but your server side code generated garbage.